# Is it possible to read list of files using mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to read list of files in a directory and store all of them in a table using mysql

For e.g I have thousand image files in this folder /User/Images

I want to store all the file names into a table in mysql.

Is it possible to do this using using just mysql, I dont want to use any programming language that has API for File read and write.

Comment: It's not possible. MySQL is a **relational database**, it deals with information and relations between them. It doesn't read directories and save info about images it finds. You use right tool for the job, like a spoon to eat soup with instead of hammer.

Comment: You could use a system tool like `ls` to create a listing, then massage it into a form that `LOAD DATA INFILE` will accept. There a suggestion that uses `sed` [here](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/45472-how-read-folder-content-file-names-export-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with the LOAD_FILE function.

`SELECT * LOAD_FILE('/home/username/myfile.txt')`

See more: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-load_file-function.php